# Simple Batch In For Loop Not Working

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

My goal is to convert some files with *.cdr extension to *.ai in a directory. The files look like file_a.cdr. file_b.cdr ...... 
I have replaced the convert.exe for you to another simple command like copy, so don't ask about the sense here in my example.

```
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    for %%f in (*.cdr) do (
    set "infile=%%f"
    set "outfile=%%~nf.ai"
    copy "%infile%" "%outfile%"
    )
```

The output of the batch is always different!!!!

Sometimes it is:

`copy "%file_a.cdr" "%file_a.ai" => system cannot find file`

or

`copy "" "" => system cannot find file`

I have already used this syntax `copy !infile! !outfile!`  with now success:

Thx in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the variables

```dos
for %%f in (*.cdr) do (
    convert "%%f" "%%~nf.ai"
)
```

Or, if you are trying to do it from command line,

```dos
for %f in (*.cdr) do convert "%f" "%~nf.ai"
```

as inside batch files percent signs need to be escaped, but this is not the case for command line.

Comment: Ah, I understand now what the 'convert.exe' phrase was about.

Comment: This is the right answer. [**Accepting Answers**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use delayed expansion. And surround your variables by ! instead of %